# How do i send json payload to endpoint and fill in header variable "key" in wso2 MI?

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

In WSO2 MI i have sequence that every 5 minutes reads from DB and logs what it got , i need send these data (in JSON format) and fill in header with "key" (some text and numbers) to endpoint. After successful sending (POST) i need to update what i sent so it will not be sent again (updating column sent from null to 1)

i use integration studio for this project

i am unsure how call mediator works (i am junior in wso2 mi), i am pretty sure that call is the way how to achieve it but in almost every example i saw there was no sending payload just calling GET and working with response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PayloadFactory Mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/payloadFactory-Mediator/) to create the payload. Then use the [property mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/property-Mediator/) or the [Header Mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/header-Mediator/) to set a Transport Header. Finally, use a [Call Mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/call-Mediator/) to send to message to the Endpoint. After the call mediator, you can check the response and do whatever you need.

```xml
<property name="Authorization" expression="$ctx:something" scope="transport" />
```

OR

```
<header name="Accept" value="image/jpeg" scope="transport"/>
```

PL Factory

```xml
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>{"newValue" : "$1"}</format>
    <args>
       <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:someProperty">
    </args>
 </payloadFactory>
```

Call Mediator

```xml
<call>
    <endpoint>
       <http method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:8080/MockService1"/>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```

Comment: how call mediator would look like ?

Comment: @GandalfCZ3 I have added the most simple version of the call mediator as well. This May differ on the way you define your endpoint.

Comment: thank you so much, i modified this code and it works

Comment: then its possible to update value of record after i sent to endpoint ?

Comment: Yes, use the appropriate mediators and update whatever you need.