# is there any way to fill transport header from file.properties?

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

in one of my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76940670/how-do-i-send-json-payload-to-endpoint-and-fill-in-header-variable-key-in-wso2) , i got solution for my header issue , it turned out that i need to get header value from file.properties

i tried following code but value is showing to be null

```
<property name="API_KEY" expression="get-property('conf:/config.properties', 'API_KEY')" scope="default" type="STRING" />

<header name="Authorization" value="Bearer $ctx:API_KEY" />
```

i also tried $FILE:API_KEY but it didnt work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have configured `file.properties` file. You can do something like below to set a transport header.

```xml
<property name="MyHeader" expression="get-property('file','YOUR_KEY_NAME')" scope="transport" />
```